# Remover letras antes e depois do número, mantendo o número

Tags: java, regex

Quero pegar a String NLS3X e usar a expressão regular para deletar o X e uma letra antes do número, ficando NL3.

Segue o código:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Drone {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.print("Entre com o comando: ");
        String entrada = sc.nextLine();


        Boolean continuar = true;

        while (continuar == true) {
            String removendoX = entrada.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z&&[^xX]][xX]", "");
           continuar = !removendoX.equals(entrada);
            entrada = removendoX.toUpperCase();
        }

        continuar = true;

        //entrada NLS3X

        while (continuar == true) {
            String removendoXmantendoNumero = entrada.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z][A-Z]", "");
            continuar = !removendoXmantendoNumero.equals(entrada);
            entrada = removendoXmantendoNumero;
        }

        System.out.println(entrada);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

A princípio, bastaria fazer:

```java
String entrada = "NLS3X";
String resultado = entrada.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z](\\d)[xX]", "$1");
```

A regex pega uma letra (`[a-zA-Z]`), seguida de um número (`\d`), seguido de um X maiúsculo ou minúsculo (`[xX]`).

O detalhe é que número está entre parênteses, o que forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Com isso, eu consigo recuperar o valor deste no segundo parâmetro: o `$1` indica que quero o primeiro par de parênteses da expressão (que no caso, é o número).

Ou seja, a regex pega uma letra qualquer, um número e a letra X, e substitui pelo número que foi encontrado. O resultado será a string `NL3`.

Note que `replaceAll` já substitui todas as ocorrências. Por exemplo, se a string for "NLS3X ABC3X DEF3X", o resultado será "NL3 AB3 DE3". A princípio não precisaria de um *loop*.

---

Entendo que um *loop* **talvez** seja necessário em casos como "NLS3XX", pois se fizermos a substituição, o resultado será "NL3X" (ou seja, ainda tem uma letra, seguida de número e X).

**Se** for para continuar substituindo até que não tenha mais a sequência "letra + número + X", aí ficaria um pouco diferente. Em vez de ficar fazendo `replaceAll` toda hora e verificando se a string foi modificada, eu sugiro usar as classes `Pattern` e `Matcher`, do [pacote `java.util.regex`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/package-summary.html):

```java
String entrada = "NLS3XX";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[a-z](\\d)x", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(entrada);
String resultado = entrada;
while (matcher.find()) {
    // substitui e atualiza o matcher para buscar na nova string
    resultado = matcher.replaceAll("$1");
    matcher.reset(resultado);
}
System.out.println(resultado);
```

Ou seja, primeiro a string "NLS3XX" é substituída por "NL3X", e na segunda iteração do `while` esta é substituída por "N3". E como agora não tem mais a sequência "letra + número + X", o *loop* se encerra.

Note que ao usar o `Pattern`, eu posso usar a *flag* `CASE_INSENSITIVE` para ignorar a diferença entre letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. Assim, posso deixar a regex apenas com letras minúsculas, que mesmo assim ela considera as maiúsculas (desta forma a regex fica um pouco mais simples).

Answer (score -3):

Cara, não conheço Java e ainda estou começando com o Python, mas consegui resolver da seguinte maneira.
Acho que dá pra passar pro Java tranquilamente.

```
import re


palavra = 'NLS3X'


palavraSemX = re.sub('[xX]','', palavra)

palavraFinal = ''


cont = 0

for letra in palavraSemX:

    if letra.isnumeric() and cont > 0:

        if not palavraFinal[len(palavraFinal) - 1].isnumeric():

            palavraFinal = palavraFinal[:len(palavraFinal) - 1]

    palavraFinal += letra
    cont += 1

print(palavra)

print(palavraFinal)
```

Comment: Não precisa dessa complicação toda, bastaria fazer `palavraFinal = re.sub(r'[a-z](\d)x', r'\1', palavra, flags=re.I)`. De qualquer forma, a ideia do site é responder na linguagem que foi perguntado, senão acaba virando bagunça. Se não sabe a linguagem em que foi perguntado, simplesmente não responda.

Comment: Exatamente a ideia é ajudar. E testei esse código é só retirou o primeiro X e a letra antes da primeiro número. Todos os outros X permaneceram assim como todas as outras letras antes de cada número. O código com toda a complicação que enviei resolveu o problema. O que é o que o rapaz precisa. Seria bom testar antes de responder. Boa noite

Comment: Esse caso de remover todos está resolvido acima na minha resposta, e o mais importante, **na linguagem em que a pergunta foi feita** (e ainda sem essa complicação toda :-) ). Esta é uma das premissas do site, usar somente a linguagem que foi pedida, não adianta só tentar ajudar se não quer seguir as regras...

Comment: Entendo e a partir de agora vou seguir as regras. O problema é o jeito que se fala. Aliás, o código que resolveu ficou tão complicado quanto o outro

Comment: Só ficou "complicado" porque Java é bem mais verbosa que Python. Porque em Python ficaria algo do tipo: https://ideone.com/RMQdId

Comment: Nisso concordo com você. Mas continua sem dar o retorno que o rapaz queria, está retornando N3 e ele queria NL3, muito menos se a string tiver mais números e outros x. De qualquer maneira, deixa pra lá. Não vale a pena ficar nessa discussão. Abs

Comment: Por favor preste atenção a um detalhe. Se a string inicial é NLS3X, o resultado é NL3. Mas no exemplo que fiz no IdeOne, a string é NLS3XX (tem dois "X" no final), então primeiro ele substitui e vira NL3X, e depois substitui de novo e vira N3 (já que tem que eliminar a letra antes do número também). Tudo bem que é discutível porque na pergunta não está claro o que fazer se tiver mais de um X, mas enfim...

Comment: Eu tinha entendido que seria para eliminar a letra antes de um número em uma única passagem, mas como você disse isso não ficou claro e realmente as duas soluções são possíveis e atendem ao que o rapaz solicitou.